# How to get the exception in nose.plugins.base.Plugin.addFailure?

Tags: python, nose

I am trying to write a plugin for nose that produces and displays additional debug information for certain kinds of exceptions in a GUI. The reason I want to do this in a plugin is because I want the GUI to be launched only when the `--enable-gui` option has been given, and plugins are the only way to add command-line options to the nose runner.

According to the documentation, I need to override `addFailure(step, err)` and `addError(step, err)`, and they say that `err` is the `sys.exc_info()` tuple:

http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html

Unfortunately, I'm getting something else entirely: The exception is replaced with the string value representing it. Here's my code:

```
def addError(self, test, err):
    info = ', '.join((type(x).__name__) for x in err)
    open('/tmp/xxxxx', 'a').write(info + '\n')

def addFailure(self, test, err):
    info = ', '.join((type(x).__name__) for x in err)
    open('/tmp/xxxxx', 'a').write(info + '\n')
```

Here's the output:

```
type, str, traceback
type, str, traceback
```

So, instead of `exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb`, I'm getting `exc_type, str(exc_value), exc_tb`.

Here's the stack of the call to my overriden methods:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtests.py", line 6, in <module>
    nose.main(module=tests, addplugins=tests.plugins.get_all_plugins())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 197, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/core.py", line 61, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kwarg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 138, in run
    result.addError(self, err)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/proxy.py", line 134, in addError
    plugins.addError(self.test, err)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 94, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 162, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "<snip>/plugins.py", line 31, in addError
    open('/tmp/xxxxx', 'a').write(info + '\n')
```

I can't extract the exception from `sys.exc_info()`, because it has already been replaced with another one (in particular, the `UnicodeEncodeError` caught during `__str__` of the raised exception).

Is there any way to extract `exc_value` from somewhere, say, the traceback?

A potential workaround: I know I can make my plugin a global variable, and instead of handling exceptions in it, I can directly send the information to the plugin itself. Unfortunately, that's not a very clean solution, so I'd like to avoid it.

Why I need a GUI: The error that I'm getting is coloured HTML traceback created by twisted, which is unreadable in the console whether I'm printing the HTML or using the `html2text` representation.

Answer (score 0):

The **err** tuple is actually: (exception type, actual exception, traceback). You should be able to access the information you need from either the exception or the traceback.

Note that in your code you write everything to a string:

```
info = ', '.join((type(x).__name__) for x in err)
```

This means it will indeed be cast to a string, which, if I understand correctly, is what you are complaining about...

Comment: I'm not casting the objects to a string, I'm simply printing their types to show that the middle element in the tuple isn't an exception, but a string.